# I am feeling, a joy and a beautiful place

Tags: riddle

> Transformation, inner space and body's grace
>
> From the eastern belt, Beauty mesmerizes the complete space
>
> Compilation between 200 bce and 200 CE was my base
>
> Name me if you can:
>
> I am a feeling , a joy and a beautiful place

Hint:

> Hint : three breaks

Comment: Is it a religious monument / place of worship or pilgrimage ?

Comment: Even I am looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a step in the proper direction or not, but there are enough similarities to venture this as a guess:

> The constellation Cassiopeia.

Transformation, inner space and body's grace

> In [Greek Mythology, Cassiopeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassiopeia_%28Queen_of_Ethiopia%29) was a vain Queen that was banished to the the "heavens" by Poseidon after claiming that she and her daughter were more beautiful than the Nereids.  She was effectively ***transformed*** from a mortal to a constellation.  ***Inner space*** could be a reference to her banishment to the sky and ***body's grace*** a reference to her self proclaimed beauty?

From the eastern belt, Beauty mesmerizes the complete space

> This could be another astronomy reference.  The Cassiopeia constellation is visible year-round for countries located in the Norther Hemisphere, which may be a tie into ***complete space***.  Because the night approaches from East (e.g. ***eastern belt***), this may also be a reference to the evening sky.

Compilation between 200 bce and 200 CE was my base

> Cassiopeia was one of the 48 constellations listed by the 2nd-century Greek astronomer Ptolemy.  This fits the timing of the riddle rather nicely.

I am a feeling , a joy and a beautiful place

> Cassiopeia was accused of being vain, and likely said something similar to this which lead to her downfall.  If you heard someone say this, you would accuse them of being rather vain as well.

Hint : three breaks

> In Chinese astronomy, the stars forming the constellation Cassiopeia are found among three areas: the Purple Forbidden enclosure (紫微垣, Zǐ Wēi Yuán), the Black Tortoise of the North (北方玄武, Běi Fāng Xuán Wǔ), and the White Tiger of the West (西方白虎, Xī Fāng Bái Hǔ).

Again, not everything here is the best fit and I do have to stretch for some things, but enough details match or are rather close that I had to post this as a possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> The Natya Shastra

Transformation, inner space and body's grace

> The religious aspect of the Natya Shastra is to "experience the essence of consciousness, and reflect on spiritual and moral questions" (Transformation and Inner Space) through the medium of dance (body's grace)

From the eastern belt, Beauty mesmerizes the complete space

> Originates in India, the Natya Sastra is described as a treatise on performance arts, which incorporate the traditional Hindu style

Compilation between 200 bce and 200 CE was my base

> The treaty's compilation date is set between these years

I am a feeling , a joy and a beautiful place

> The Natya Shastra describes three categories of performance, the Nritta, described as "pure dance performance; abstract, fast, and rhythmic"; the Nritya, "slower and expressional, conveys feelings"; and the Natya, "a play", also described as "helping to connect and transport the individual into a super sensual inner state of being"

Three breaks

> The Natya Shastra breaks the performance down into 3 pieces as described above.

Please note, this wasn't something I had prior knowledge of. The three breaks hint combined with the date range was plenty for me to do some light research and find something that seemed to succinctly fit the riddle.